On the Differentiability of f∘g when range of g is same as domain of f.
It is well-known that a function can be continuous at a point without being differentiable there. This occurs when the graph exhibits a sharp corner at that point, preventing the existence of a unique tangent line. While many such functions are defined piecewise, I have encountered examples that are not defined piecewise, like $arcsin((2x)/(1+x²))$. I observed a similar behavior in the function $arcsin(Ω(x))$, where $Ω(x)$ = $(2x^{a})/(1+x^{2a})$ and 'a' is an odd integer. Specifically, this function is continuous but not differentiable at -1 and 1. I noticed that the domain of arcsine and the range of Ω coincide at [-1, 1]. So can we say that it is true in general that,
"Let $f$ be either $arcsin$ or $arccos$ function and $g$ be continuous function such that the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and Range of $g$ is [-1,1] and
$\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ = $g(a)$ = 1 for some a ∈ $\mathbb{R}$
Consider the composite function $h=f∘g$. Then $h$ is continuous but not differentiable at $a$" ?

Provided that I am understanding your question correctly, the answer is no. If $a=-1$ and $b=1$, the function $g=\sin$, and $f$ is the identity function on $[-1,1]$, then $h=f\circ g=\sin$ is both continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb R$. In particular, it is differentiable at $-1$ and $1$.

Let's say f is arcsine or arccos then that statement will hold true for all such g with domain R and range [-1,1]?

Take $g=\sin$ again. Then, $\arcsin\circ g$ looks like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uwnlabr1zi. As you can see: it is differentiable at $-1$ and $1$.

There is a reason for this: the function $\arcsin$ exhibits unpleasant behaviour near $-1$ and $1$, so you want to look at what $g$ does when $g(x)$ is close to $1$ or close to $-1$, not when $x$ is close to $1$ or $-1$.

Thank you , It was helpful. Indeed, it appears that the critical points of interest are those where the function g(x) assumes the values of 1 or -1. At these points, the composition arcsin(g(x)) simplifies to arcsin(1) or arcsin(-1), respectively, exhibiting anomalous differentiability properties.
